# ASP.Net Table Format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to implement this in my `aspx` page

```
<div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table table-striped     table-bordered table-hover">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>                                                
                                                    <td><strong>Make</strong></td>
                                                    <td>MAN</td>                                                    
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>                                                    
                                                    <td><strong>Model</strong></td>
                                                    <td>8DC9</td>                                                       
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>                                
                                                    <td><strong>Engine No.</strong></td>
                                                    <td>8DC9-12334</td>

                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.table-responsive -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.panel-body -->
                        </div>
```

currently i have this in my `aspx` page

```
div class="panel panel-default" style="border: 0px">
                         <div class="table-resposinve">
                         <asp:Table CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" runat="server" ID="tbl_TruckData">



                                 <asp:TableHeaderCell>
                                 Truck ID
                                     <asp:TableHeaderRow>
                                     </asp:TableHeaderRow>
                                    </asp:TableHeaderCell>


                                 <asp:TableHeaderRow>

                                 <asp:TableHeaderCell>
                                 Registration Number
                                     </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                              </asp:TableHeaderRow>


                                 <asp:TableHeaderRow>

                                 <asp:TableHeaderCell>
                                 Make
                                     </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                              </asp:TableHeaderRow>

                                    <asp:TableHeaderRow>

                                 <asp:TableHeaderCell>
                           Model
                                     </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                              </asp:TableHeaderRow>

                                 <asp:TableHeaderRow>

                                 <asp:TableHeaderCell>
                                Engine No.
                                     </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                              </asp:TableHeaderRow>

                                 <asp:TableHeaderRow>

                                 <asp:TableHeaderCell>
                                Chassis No.
                                     </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                              </asp:TableHeaderRow>

                                 <asp:TableHeaderRow>

                                 <asp:TableHeaderCell>
                                 Driver Name
                                     </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                              </asp:TableHeaderRow>

                                 <asp:TableHeaderRow>

                                 <asp:TableHeaderCell>
                                Driver Contact No.
                                     </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                              </asp:TableHeaderRow>

                                 <asp:TableHeaderRow>

                                 <asp:TableHeaderCell>
                                Status

                             </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                              </asp:TableHeaderRow>
                             </asp:Table>
```

The result is very distorted, 
i want to make the label and the data horizontally aligned
How can i make an vertical table in asp.net webforms

and i have this on my `aspx.cs`

```
 private void populateTable(MySqlDataReader mySqlDataReader)
    {
        foreach (DbDataRecord rowData in mySqlDataReader)
        {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();

            TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
            cell2.Text = rowData.GetInt32(rowData.GetOrdinal("truck_id")).ToString();
            tr.Cells.Add(cell2);

            TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
            cell3.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("registration_no")).ToString();
            tr.Cells.Add(cell3);

            TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
            cell4.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("make")).ToString();
            tr.Cells.Add(cell4);

            TableCell cell5 = new TableCell();
            cell5.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("model")).ToString();
            tr.Cells.Add(cell5);

            TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
            cell1.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("engine_no")).ToString();
            tr.Cells.Add(cell1);

            TableCell cell6 = new TableCell();
            cell6.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("chassis_no")).ToString();
            tr.Cells.Add(cell6);

            TableCell cell7 = new TableCell();
            cell7.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("driver_name")).ToString();
            tr.Cells.Add(cell7);

            TableCell cell8 = new TableCell();
            cell8.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("driver_contact_no")).ToString();
            tr.Cells.Add(cell8);

            TableCell cell9 = new TableCell();
            cell9.Text = rowData.GetString(rowData.GetOrdinal("status")).ToString();
            tr.Cells.Add(cell9);

            tbl_TruckData.Rows.Add(tr);
        }
    }
```

What should i replace so that it would render horizontally

Comment: Just use the usual HTML tags.

Comment: If you want to show what you are after, why not show the rendered HTML? And why not show specifically what is not rendering as you want? It's too much work to compare every line to see what isn't as you want. Also, did you misspell here: `<div class="table-resposinve">`?

Answer (score 0):

Your first row is incorrect:

```
<asp:TableHeaderCell>
Truck ID
<asp:TableHeaderRow>
</asp:TableHeaderRow>
</asp:TableHeaderCell>
```

You need to put the cells inside the row, not the opposite. Change it to:

```
<asp:TableHeaderRow>
  <asp:TableHeaderCell>Truck ID</asp:TableHeaderCell>
</asp:TableHeaderRow>
```

Now with that fix, you need to put two cells in each row, exactly like in your HTML example, so the first row becomes:

```
<asp:TableHeaderRow>
  <asp:TableHeaderCell>Truck ID</asp:TableHeaderCell>
  <asp:TableHeaderCell>123456</asp:TableHeaderCell>
</asp:TableHeaderRow>
```

Of course, instead of the values "Truck ID" and "123456", you should use an ASP controls such as `Label`.